# Trying to import module with the same name as a built-in module causes an import error

Tags: python, python-import

I have a module that conflicts with a built-in module.  For example, a `myapp.email` module defined in `myapp/email.py`.

I can reference `myapp.email` anywhere in my code without issue.  However, I need to reference the built-in email module from my email module.

```
# myapp/email.py
from email import message_from_string
```

It only finds itself, and therefore raises an `ImportError`, since `myapp.email` doesn't have a `message_from_string` method.  `import email` causes the same issue when I try `email.message_from_string`.

Is there any native support to do this in Python, or am I stuck with renaming my "email" module to something more specific?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You will want to read about [Absolute and Relative Imports](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-328-absolute-and-relative-imports) which addresses this very problem. Use:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

Using that, any unadorned package name will always refer to the top level package. You will then need to use relative imports (`from .email import ...`) to access your own package.

**NOTE:** The above `from ...` line needs to be put into any 2.x Python `.py` files above the `import ...` lines you're using. In Python 3.x this is the default behavior and so is no longer needed.