# PyCharm module name conflicts

Tags: python, import, path, pycharm

I have a module named 'io' in my package: **mypackage.io**. This causes a conflict with the Python built-in io package. Thus, whenever I use PyCharm to perform debugging of my code, since pydev helper uses gzip (which in turns uses io), I encounter a module ImportError. The problem is partly due to PyCharm automatically add my package path to the interpreter path. So I am left with two options

- From the answer of [Trying to import module with the same name as a built-in module causes an import error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224741/python-import-with-name-conflicts), it seems that I need to make changes to gzip.py so that it will import io by absolute importing.
- Rename my module from io to something_else

Am I missing a better solution?

Comment: ops, downvoted by mistake :( sorry

Comment: upvoted, didn't think this deserved a -1 :-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically have two options:

1. Rename your custom package
2. Explicitly use mypackage.io.foo instead of io.foo

Generally speaking, its bad form to map a custom package atop a built-in unless you are intentionally changing that default builtin's behavior.  Any short-term game will be offset by many, long-term headaches.