# How do I resolve namespace conflicts in my Python packages with standard library package names?

Tags: python, package, namespaces

I am developing a package with the following structure on disk:

```
foo/
   __init__.py
   xml.py
   bar.py
   moo.py
```

The `xml.py` package provides a class that does some custom XML parsing and translation for the other package components using a SAX stream parser. So it has in it:

```
import xml.sax
import xml.sax.handler
```

But when I go to use `foo.xml` in an application I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testxmlparser.py", line 15, in <module>
    import foo.xml
  File "~/code/foo/xml.py", line 39, in <module>
    import xml.sax
ImportError: No module named sax
```

I appear to have a namespace conflict. If I rename `xml.py` to something else like `xmlparser.py` everything works as expected. But this feels like the wrong thing to do. I feel like I'm missing something fundamental about package names and resolution in Python here.

Is there a proper way to make this work that doesn't involve me renaming the `foo/xml.py` file? Or is that really the only solution to the conflicting names?

Edit: The "avoid naming things the same as standard Python modules" seems...well..a mineshaft to me. That's a moving target, the standard module set, that's bound to change and grow over time. So unless you get *really* creative with your names the rename-things-until-you-find-something-that-doesn't-conflict solutions seems poor to me. Besides, I've got it in a unique package name with `foo` already (I'm not using `foo`, but something that is definitely unique), shouldn't that be enough?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As mentioned [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224741/python-import-with-name-conflicts/1224760#1224760), use

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

and use [relative imports](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#guido-s-decision) if needed.

Comment: The problem is `xml.sax` isn't in *my* package. So a relative import of it doesn't work. That's actually why it's failing for me right now. Python expects `xml.sax` to be relative to my `foo.xml` package, but it's not.