# Import package from file with same name as package

Tags: python, module, package

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python import with name conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224741/python-import-with-name-conflicts)

I have a script file called `email.py` in which I need to import the `email` module from the Python standard library. Unfortunately, when I do an `import email` in my `email.py` file the `email.py` file itself is imported.

How can I tell Python that I want to import the standard library package?

Cheers

Comment: @bgporter just as I said below.

Comment: Although this may be an exact duplicate, the Google found this question (and not the other one) when I searched "python import package from file of same name". So I'm sure glad it's here for the redirect.