# Python 3 package module conflicts with standard module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

I recently decided to upgrade to python 3, and start converting some of my scripts. I encountered a problem in a script that uses a module named `io` - in python 2, this is perfectly fine, however in python 3, `io` is a standard module for files. I found [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224741/python-import-with-name-conflicts) about the same kind of problem, however this appears to be in reference to python 2. I have the opposite problem - given two files, `main.py` and `io.py` in the top level package, `import io` in `main.py` will import the standard `io` module, not the local one. `from __future__ import absolute_imports` didn't help, and `from . import io` and related attempts fail as expected (which I have never understood - python really doesn't know where the top level package is?). Renaming is obviously a solution, but if possible I'd like to avoid it. Is there some python 3 standard way of resolving module name conflicts?

Comment: There's a similar question and answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224741/python-import-with-name-conflicts

Comment: Yes, I linked that: "I found [this old question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224741/python-import-with-name-conflicts) about the same kind of problem, however this appears to be in reference to python 2."

Comment: In Python3, absolute imports are default. So:-

`from .base import BaseThing`
The leading . says 'import Base from module directory'; in other words, `.base` maps to `./base.py`.

Comment: Or `from .io import *` for your case.

Comment: `from .io import *` throws `SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import` because both modules are in the top level package. Related forms like `from . import io` throw the same error.

Comment: Please include the full traceback in the question.

Comment: @LevLevitsky: That's the whole traceback. `main.py` is invoked from terminal, runs `from .io import *`, throws error. No function calls or anything.

Comment: Do you have `__init.py__` in the package dir? If not, can you try creating an empty file with that name?

Comment: I tried with and without `__init__.py`, same error. At least in python 2, this was default behavior - I experienced similar problems in unrelated scripts and could never figure out why (from a technical standpoint) python doesn't allow relative imports in the top level package.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer:-

My directory structure:-

```
calvin$ tree /Users/calvin/work/learn3/
/Users/calvin/work/learn3/
└── myspecialpackage
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.pyc
    ├── io.py
    ├── io.pyc
    └── main.py
```

`__init__.py` is an empty file.

`io.py` is your custom module which conflicts with python3's io module.

`main.py` contains this bunch of example code:-

```
import os
import sys

# These two lines are not needed you are installing the `myspecialpackage` via pip/pypi and as setup.py script places "myspecialpackage" and all its contents in your python site-packages, which is already in PYTHONPATH.
our_package_root = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
sys.path.append(our_package_root)

from myspecialpackage import io
print(io.__file__)
```

And the imported `io` module will be the one in your `io.py` and not python3's module.

As a bonus, using this methodology will allow us to have your custom `io.py` as well as python3's `io` module (if you so desire having your cake and eat it ;-)).  You can deconflict the use of the namespace `io` like this:-

```
from myspecialpackage import io as my_special_io
print(my_special_io.__file__)

import io
print(io.__file__)
```

Running `main.py` will then give you:-

```
In [3]: run myspecialpackage/main.py
/Users/calvin/work/learn3/myspecialpackage
./myspecialpackage/io.py
/Users/calvin/.virtualenvs/learn3/bin/../lib/python3.3/io.py
```

Take note of the comment I made above regarding

```
our_package_root = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
sys.path.append(our_package_root)
```

Comment: This doesn't work either - seems to be related to the other answer (that the author deleted?) which suggested `sys.path.insert(1, '/path/to/package')`. Is it possible that my installation is misconfigured? I also noticed that you're using 2.7, and I have 3.3. Does that change anything significantly?

Comment: That's not important. I was using iPython shell to do some print outs which still uses python2. Python normal shell works fine.

Comment: Are you sure you are following exactly the directory structure I described above?

Comment: The only difference is that `__init__.py` has no corresponding `.pyc`. That shouldn't change anything, though.

Comment: The important part is to import your special io module using the `from myspecialpackage import io` syntax. This guarantees that that `io` you are importing comes from `myspecialpackage` and not the system-wide/python3's io.py.

Comment: Ah - I didn't pick that up the first time. With that it throws `ImportError: bad magic number in 'a_package': b'\x03\xf3\r\n'`. I have no idea what that's supposed to be telling me.

Comment: Changing sys.path is unrelated to OP's issue that is solved by putting the modules inside myspecialpackage and using absolute imports. btw, `learn3` should be in sys.path, not `myspecialpackage` directory. `python -mmyspecialpackage.main` should work without modifying sys.path inside main.py.

Comment: @Monchoman45: "bad magic number" means that you're trying to use a pyc-file generated by a different Python version. Note: Python 3 adds the version in the file name so there shouldn't be any conflict (in addition Python 3 puts pyc-files to `__pycache__` directory). Just delete pyc-files; they will be regenerated when necessary

Comment: That worked, however now it throws `ImportError: No module named 'myspecialpackage'`. This I would assume is because it's the top level package?

Comment: It means that your `myspecialpackage` is still not in `PYTHONPATH`

Comment: `myspecialpackage` is the first entry in `sys.path` - however per @J.F.Sebastian above, should it actually be the directory above `myspecialpackage`?