# How do I import and/or reference a user-defined module with the same name as a built-in Python name

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
Project
    __init__.py
    main.py
    parser.py
```

From within main, how do I import my my parser module given that parser is already a built-in?

Current, renaming the user-defined module is the **worst-case** solution.

I've tried:

```
import parser
from parser import  TextFileParser

from parser import TextFileParser

from . import parser

from .parser import TextFileParser

from __future__ import absolute_import
from . import parser as myParser
```

as well as a few other combinations.

I've read the answer [to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224741/trying-to-import-module-with-the-same-name-as-a-built-in-module-causes-an-import/1224760#1224760) related question, but my understanding is that 3.5 uses absolute imports by default. I also read this [article](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-328-absolute-and-relative-imports), but it didn't seem to apply.

I'm also happy aliasing the class I need, if that is possible. i.e.

`TextParseClass = from parser import TextParser`

Comment: There is some automation code that depends on this being the name. Also, I think the issue will come up again, such as the Python standard library expanding to include a new built-in that overwrites a module I've made

Comment: @Jordy Cuan Petrucci Ugh, I feel embarrassed. So simple not sure how I overlooked it. Thanks. Make it an answer if you want

Comment: `__import__("Project.parser")` will return your module as well. So `foo = __import__("Project.parser")` should work although it's probably not the best way to handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this: `from Project import parser`