# how to use absolute paths in flask app?

Tags: python, flask

I'm attempting to learn python and can't seem to understand how python handles imports. I'm experimenting with a Flask app and i can get it to run with relative urls, but i want to use absolute urls as an exercise to learn about imports.

I've set my `PYTHONPATH` to my `app` directory inside my project but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Here's my setup. I've got `app/__init.py` on the left and `app/mod_users/controllers.py` on the right. My `run.py` is a file with one line, `from app import app`.

As you can see on line 17, it doesn't like the absolute import. Could this be because my app variable is named `app` and so is the import path?

[image]

Comment: Seems like that is the case, this post may offer a workaround without having to change names: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1224741/1248974

Comment: that did it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

After some experimenting thanks to @downshift I think i've figured it out. 4 steps get me to to state i want.

1. Add this line to the top of my `app/__init.py`

   ```
   from __future__ import absolute_import
   ```
2. `export PYTHONPATH=./`
3. `export FLASK_APP=app` (and `FLASK_DEBUG=1` for live reload)
4. Change `run.py` to

   ```
   from app import app
   app.run()
   ```

If i do the above i can use both `flask run` and `python run.py` and they work the same. Woo hoo!