# object has no attribute 'API' error in falcon

Tags: python, falconframework, falcon

I am using `python 2.7.6` on `ubuntu 14.04` with falcon web framework and trying to run simple hello world program. But it gives the following error while running this example. Any idea about this?

**Code :**

```
import falcon

class ThingsResource(object):
    def on_get(self, req, resp):
        """Handles GET requests"""
        resp.status = falcon.HTTP_200
        resp.body = 'Hello world!'

# falcon.API instances are callable WSGI apps
wsgi_app = api = falcon.API()

# Resources are represented by long-lived class instances
things = ThingsResource()

# things will handle all requests to the '/things' URL path
api.add_route('/hello', things)
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "falcon.py", line 1, in <module>
    import falcon
  File "/home/naresh/Desktop/PythonFramework/falcon.py", line 10, in <module>
    wsgi_app = api = falcon.API()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'API'
```

Comment: You probably named your python file falcon.py right ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your python file is falcon.py so when you call `falcon.API()` you are calling a method `API()` in your file, not from the real falcon module.

Just rename your file and it will work.

---

For a more complete solution, see this :

[Trying to import module with the same name as a built-in module causes an import error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224741/trying-to-import-module-with-the-same-name-as-a-built-in-module-causes-an-import) :

> You will want to read about Absolute and Relative Imports which
>   addresses this very problem. Use:
>
> ```
> from __future__ import absolute_import Using that, any unadorned package name will always refer to the top level package. You will then
> ```
>
> need to use relative imports (from .email import ...) to access your
>   own package.