# how to fix issue with ssl.socket

Tags: python, sockets, ssl

I have this python code which getting data from socket's and printing to console. But in working process I getting this error code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 1, in <module>
    import ssl, socket
  File "/home/ssl.py", line 20, in <module>
    returned from time.time())
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'wrap_socket'
```

maybe somebody has any idea how I can fix this issue?

```
import ssl, socket
sock = ssl.wrap_socket(socket.socket(), 'server.key', 'server.crt', True)
sock.bind( ('', 443) )
sock.listen(10)
while True:
        conn, addr = sock.accept()
        data = conn.recv(4)
        print data
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have a file named `ssl.py` in the same directory, as indicated by this part of the error:

> File "/home/ssl.py", line 20, in 
>       returned from time.time())

and the script is trying to import that instead of the system level module. If you cannot change the name of that file, try using [absolute and relative imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224741/trying-to-import-module-with-the-same-name-as-a-built-in-module-causes-an-import/1224760#1224760).