# import Python module when there is sibling file with the same name

Tags: python

Suppose I have following files

```
tata/foo.py
tata/yoyo.py

foo/__init__.py
foo/bar.py
```

In file `foo.py` I do

```
import foo.bar
```

I run `PYTHONPATH=. python tata/yoyo.py` and I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tata/yoyo.py", line 1, in <module>
    import foo.bar
ImportError: No module named bar
```

Issue disappears when I delete `tata/foo.py`. Could you please suggest a way to resolve my situation when I have global module name and local file name coincides.

Comment: have you tried `PYTHONPATH=$PWD` instead?

Comment: I have tried just now and found that it does not work in the same way

Comment: [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224741/trying-to-import-module-with-the-same-name-as-a-built-in-module-causes-an-import/1224760#1224760)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an example:

files:

```
test
|
import_test
├── foo
│   ├── bar.py
│   ├── bar.pyc
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── __init__.pyc
├── __init__.py
├── __init__.pyc
└── tata
    ├── foo.py
    ├── foo.pyc
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.pyc
    └── yoyo.py
```

yoyo.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8
from __future__ import absolute_import
from ..foo import bar


print 'cool'
```

Test command:

```
cd test    
python -m import_test.tata.yoyo
```

output:

```
cool
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a classical issue described in [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/)

> a local module or package can shadow another hanging directly off sys.path

to deal with it:

1. Code should be executed as module rather than script (`-m` option).
2. Use Python 3 which has so-called "absolute import behaviour" or add

   ```
   from __future__ import absolute_import
   ```