# Python3: import excluding local module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a module called `goofy` on my django project. The problem now is I want to use a thirdy package installed using pip. The package is `pygoofy`, but the module name used to import is the same as mine: `goofy`.

Now I can’t use the installed package because every time I try to import `goofy` I get mine local package. I can’t rename my package and I’m thinking the only way is to use `importlib`, but I didn’t find how to use it. Any suggestion?

**Update**: The answer available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224741/trying-to-import-module-with-the-same-name-as-a-built-in-module-causes-an-import) is for python2