# Error running OpenTok Server Code (Python)

Tags: python, opentok

I have problem running `flask run` for OpenTok server code. How can I eradicate the error? Thanks in advance.

This is the error:

```
(opentokenv) ➜  opentok-server python -m flask run
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/__main__.py", line 15, in <module>
    main(as_module=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 513, in main
    cli.main(args=args, prog_name=name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 380, in main
    return AppGroup.main(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 697, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 895, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 535, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 64, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args[1:], **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 535, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 423, in run_command
    app = DispatchingApp(info.load_app, use_eager_loading=eager_loading)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 152, in __init__
    self._load_unlocked()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 176, in _load_unlocked
    self._app = rv = self.loader()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 237, in load_app
    rv = locate_app(self.app_import_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 90, in locate_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/Users/azambaderi/Documents/Web_Projects/opentok-server/opentok.py", line 2, in <module>
    from opentok import OpenTok
ImportError: cannot import name OpenTok
```

This is the Python code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from opentok import OpenTok
import os

try:
    api_key = os.environ['API_KEY']
    api_secret = os.environ['API_SECRET']
except Exception:
    raise Exception('You must define API_KEY and API_SECRET environment variables')

app = Flask(__name__)
opentok = OpenTok(api_key, api_secret)
session = opentok.create_session()

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    key = api_key
    session_id = session.session_id
    token = opentok.generate_token(session_id)
    return render_template('index.html', api_key=key, session_id=session_id, token=token)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code and it worked for me, until I changed the filename to `opentok.py` (from the stack trace it appears that is the name you are using).

I think the quickest solution here is to change your filename from `opentok.py` to something else as it conflicting with the library name. (Don't forget to remove the `opentok.pyc` file too).

If you wish to keep the name you should see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1224760/5433407) about [Absolute and Relative imports](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-328-absolute-and-relative-imports)

Comment: Thanks Mike. I can run flask now.