# Python - Conflict Between My Package Name And Installed Package Name

Tags: python

I am trying to call `jwt.encode` function of `PyJWT` but it's probably conflicting with my package `jwt` and thus giving the error `AttributeError("module 'jwt' has no attribute 'encode'")`

- I am running a virtual environment.
- Python version 3.6.7
- According the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224741/trying-to-import-module-with-the-same-name-as-a-built-in-module-causes-an-import) in Python versions 3.x this shouldn't be a problem.

My application structure is as below

```
jwt
 |-- __init__.py
 |-- db.py
instance
 |-- jwt.sqlite
tests
 |-- __init__.py
 |-- conftest.py
 |-- test_encodetoken.py
```

I get the error when I run

`(venv) ~$ pytest`

I put an empty `__init__.py` in `tests` folder because otherwise it cannot find my `jwt` package.

Below is the function calling `jwt.encode` which is inside `db.py`

```
import jwt
def encode_auth_token(user_id,app):
    """
    Generates the Auth Token
    :return: string
    """
    try:
        payload = {
            'exp': datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(days=0, seconds=5),
            'iat': datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
            'sub': user_id
        }
        return jwt.encode(
            payload,
            app.config.get('SECRET_KEY'),
            algorithm='HS256'
        )
    except Exception as e:
        return e
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix: Rename the directory `jwt`

Why: Since your code is before the library's code in the `PYTHONPATH` you code is seen and not the `jwt` from `PyJWT`

Example:

```
dbutils
 |-- __init__.py
 |-- db.py
instance
 |-- jwt.sqlite
tests
 |-- __init__.py
 |-- conftest.py
 |-- test_encodetoken.py
```

Comment: I would like to understand the concept behind `PYTHONPATH` a bit more so I am able to import the library code if such an issue occurs again. Could you suggest how can I do that?