# python3 import name conflict with import cycle

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python has package named `ast`, I want to import it, but I also have same name called `ast`, `pycharm` also show me local ast reference.

From docs

python3 use absolute import, so

```
import ast
```

should import python standard library

How to import python standard lib **without renaming** my ast file?

*I am using Python 3.7*

[image]

Comment: Absolute imports have nothing to do with stdlib vs third-party modules, despite what some poorly-worded tutorials may say. Absolute imports just mean `import ast` always tries to import the `ast` module instead of `currentpackage.ast` (and no, `venv` is not a package and should not be a package).

Comment: Pick a different name.

Comment: Is eventloop a package, or just a folder containing the top-level files of your application? In the former case, it should have a __init__.py file, and then 'import ast' should not resolve to your file anymore (that would be 'import eventloop.ast'). In the latter case, well, you are creating a name clash between the standard library and your project, and I see no solution to your problem.

Comment: @Pierre-Antoine just a folder

Comment: FTR, I do not consider this question to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224741/trying-to-import-module-with-the-same-name-as-a-built-in-module-causes-an-import . They are of course related, but absolute import are the solution to the previous question; not to that one...

Comment: I suggest you make 'eventloop' a package. That would allow you to keep the file hierarchy as is, without renaming your files. That would require only minor change to your python files: replacing `import ast` by `import .ast` or `import eventloop.ast`. And you would get rid of the name clash.