# Can I import a local module with the same name as a standard-library one?

Tags: python, python-import

I created my own module named `queue`, and am trying to import it. However, when trying to use it, I get the error `'Queue' object has no attribute 'enqueue'`.

How can I import my own queue (which *does* have an `enqueue`), and not the standard-library one (which does not)?

```
def driver():
    import queue
    q = queue.Queue()
    for line in df:
        if 'received' in line:
            q.enqueue(line)
            print("Adding job " + new_item.job_ID + " to the queue with the timestamp: " + new_item.time_stamp + ".")
            print("The prority of the job is: " + new_item.job_priority)
            print("The job type is: " + new_item.job_type)
```

Comment: You're almost certainly importing `queue` from the standard library. Probably best to rename your `queue` module to avoid confusion

Comment: Exactly -- you're getting the standard-library `queue`, and its `Queue` implementations have `get()` and `put()`, not `enqueue()`.

Comment: This is very closely related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224741/trying-to-import-module-with-the-same-name-as-a-built-in-module-causes-an-import

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing from builtin library when module with same name exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031584/importing-from-builtin-library-when-module-with-same-name-exists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename your internal file to something like `my_queue.py` and import it into your file like this. That avoids bad practices like `from queue import *` and name conflicts with the standard library which is most likely the problem you are running into now.

```
import my_queue

def driver():
    q = my_queue.Queue()
    for line in df:
        if 'received' in line:
            q.enqueue(line)
            print("Adding job " + new_item.job_ID + " to the queue with the timestamp: " + new_item.time_stamp + ".")
            print("The prority of the job is: " + new_item.job_priority)
            print("The job type is: " + new_item.job_type)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2.x, you can gain the ability to disambiguate between your local `queue` and the standard-library one by adding the following line before any other imports:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

...and then using:

```
import .queue as local_queue
q = local_queue.Queue()
```

...to get your own implementation, not the standard one.

---

In Python 3, this behavior is default, so you don't need the `from __future__ import` to be able to use `import .queue` to explicitly import from a `queue.py` in the same package or directory as your current code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the proble is that python is importing it's buit-in module queue, so when instanciating a Queue class, you are creating an object of the pthon built-in type queue.

a solution to this problem is changing the module and the class name, and there is this convention in python when creating a function, a module or class with the same name as a built-in function, module or name is that you should add a `_` to the end of your own module and class,

so, may be try

```
 queue ==> queue_
 Queue ==> Queue_
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
from queue import *

q = Queue ()

def driver():
    for line in df:
        if 'received' in line:
            q.enqueue(line)
            print("Adding job " + new_item.job_ID + " to the queue with the timestamp: " + new_item.time_stamp + ".")
            print("The prority of the job is: " + new_item.job_priority)
            print("The job type is: " + new_item.job_type)
```

Comment: Why would this import the local queue module if `import queue` imports the standard-library one? It's strictly worse, insofar as it's wildcard imports introduce namespace pollution, and it doesn't change the behavior that's actually causing the OP trouble.